# Windows Server 2012 member server cannot authenticate to domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

We have a simple domain for some servers, with a single domain controller "APP01", and another member server "APP02"

For an unrelated reason, one of our services on APP02 fails and needs restarting, but this fails due to a credential problem. It looks like that after some time, the member server looses its connection to the domain, and can no longer authenticate.

If I look in the service properties to see what user account it's logging in as, it is set to myuser@mydomain.local with the correct password, and shortly after a reboot that validates okay and the service starts. Once the server is in "failure mode", I can no longer browse the domain for users, and the "Locations" screen now only shows APP02 as an option, and the "entire directory" option is missing - almost as if this was a standalone server.

Oddly, if I browse to \APP01\MyShare, I get prompted for credentials and login is successful if I enter the service username and password.

Comment: Anything in event logs (on both machines)? Time is synchronized (assuming kerberos time issue)? THis seriously is an odd error. All patched up?

Comment: Okay this is odd. APP02 has US regional settings, and APP01 has UK (correct) settings. Both appear to have the correct time though. Both are in UTC

Comment: Hmm, I changed the system region to UK, and that seems to have fixed it. So it wasn't directly time-sync related, but you put me on the right track.

Comment: Ok, this is EXTREMELY odd. No idea - that should not happen.

Comment: Still sounds like a kerberos time skew issue, access to \\APP01\MyShare would have defaulted the NTLM over SMB for authentication. If the `LAN Manager Authentication Level` policy is set low or Extended Protection is suppressed, NTLM auth reqs can still succeed